# The definition of a topology

Tags: general-topology

In *Tensor Analysis on Manifolds* by Bishop and Goldberg, they state the definition of a topology as the following:

> A *topology* on a set $X$ is a subset $T$ of $\mathscr{P}X$, $T\subset
>  \mathscr{P}X$, such that
>
> (a) If $G_1,G_2\in T$, then $G_1\cap G_2\in T$.
>
> (b) If $\left\{G_\alpha\big|\alpha\in J\right\}\subset T$, then
>   $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in J}G_\alpha \in T$.
>
> (c) $\varnothing\in T$ and $\color{red}{X\in T}$.

Why is it that $X\in T$? It seems it should be $T\in X$ since $T\subset \mathscr{P}X$. So why is the former true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a subset of $X$, hence an element of $\mathscr PX$. So it makes perfect sense to say that $X \in T \subset \mathscr PX$. However, it doesn't make sense to say that $T \in X$; $T$ is not a point of $X$.

Comment: Would that perhaps make $T$ a *collection* of "points" in $X$, since it is by definition a subset of $\mathscr{P}X$?

Comment: Nope, @jm324354. A collection of points in $X$ would be a *subset* of $X$ - but we're going deeper. $T$ is a collection of points of $\mathscr PX$ - that is, a collection of subsets of $X$ - that is, a collection of (collections of points of $X$). :)

Comment: Awesome, this makes total sense now. I've learned two things (as pathetic as that is, but ehh, I'm just a beginner in all this "abstract stuff")

Comment: That's not pathetic, @jm. It's tough stuff, especially at first! Good luck on your adventures.

Answer (score 2):

An subset $T$ of the powerset of X is a collection of subsets of $X$.  So it's perfectly reasonable that $X$,  being a subset of $X$, be in $T$.

On the other hand, it makes no sense that $T \in X$: $T$ is collection of subsets of $X$.